# How to avoid empty FIFO when the read clk is higher than the write clk

Tags: fpga, vhdl, fifo

I have an ADC, and, in order to avoid sync problems, I have used a FIFO with two different clocks: one for the write operation, that works at the ADC clock frequency and the other, FPGA clock that is higher than the ADC clock and is for the read operation. The depth of the FIFO is 8192, but i can set to more depth: 16384, 32768, 65536 or 131072. But I think the depth of the FIFO is not important here.

ADC is an extern hardware with his own clock. Maybe can occurs offsets between the ADC clock and the FPGA clock. Also, the ADC sets the output in the positive and negative edge of the ADC clock so it is necessary use an IDDR to catch the data in both edges.

The problem is that, obviously, the FIFO at a specified time, will be empty...

The relation between  both clocks freqs. are:

$$CLK_{FPGA} = 4·CLK_{AD}$$

So, for each four readings in the FIFO, one writing occurs.

What is the better aproach to sync the dada between 2 different clocks when the read clock is highest than the write clock? Is optimal use a FIFO for this purposes?

The first way to resolve the problem that I though is use the the `almost_full` flag to fill at the begining at the maximun the FIFO and later start to read, but either way, the FIFO agains will be empty.

Thanks!

Comment: Pointless using a FIFO if the overall collection rate from the ADC by the FPGA is not the limitation. *But I think the depth of the FIFO is not important here* - exactly, a depth of zero seems a good choice to me.

Comment: This is why you have status flags that indicate when the FIFO is empty or not. If it's empty, you don't read from it. Similarly, this is why you have flags that indicate when the FIFO is full so that you don't write to it.

Comment: If the clocks are synchronous to each other, eliminate the FIFO as Andy suggests, and use CLK(AD) as an enable to read from the ADC interface. And if they aren't, consider making them synchronous...

Comment: DIego, the reason I can imagine for a FIFO in this case is where you ***need*** the ADC to sample a signal at a high rate and where the processing of that data doesn't have to keep up with it, but can be performed at a later time. You might just as well use a buffer of the right size. Do you need to sample at a rate that is much higher than your read rate?

Comment: Hi @jonk Yes, I need a read frequency of 250 MHz in order to save dsp's in the FPGA when the pre-distortion be applied to the signal via Neural Networks in order to linearize the output of the PA. The ADC clock can be defined from 30 MSPS to 65 MSPS, so I have taken a frequency of 62.5 MHz for the ADC clock. Using the control signals of almost_empty and almost_full I will fill the FIFO in order to achieve read chunks of 432 bits that is the payload where the pre-distortion will be applied.

Comment: If it's empty, then don't dequeue / read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your FPGA logic reading the data can immediately stop when the FIFO is empty, then you don't have a problem. For example, if you use an AXI-Stream FIFO, the read port will give a not-valid condition when you read 'till the end. (That's a good reason to consider using AXI-S by the way: it solves this problem very neatly, using the data-stationary VALID flag.)

If your read logic has some latency in responding to the empty condition, then you will need to use almost-empty instead to compensate for that latency.

Since you've stated that your read rate is higher than the ADC production rate, I'll assume you don't need a write skid buffer to deal with the almost-full condition. That wouldn't make sense for an ADC anyway, as an ADC inherently cannot ever be stalled.

Answer (score 0):

**Is important to keep the FIFO from becoming empty?**
Be sure you are not trying to solve a problem that doesn’t exist. Your question doesn’t provide enough details regarding your application, but unless you need regularly spaced samples, just use the EMPTY flag.

**If you must keep synchronization , why not just read the ADC at the ADC frequency?**
Since you indicated that your FPGA clock has a 4:1 ratio with the ADC sampling frequency, simply use a 2-bit counter to gate (clock enable) your FPGA reads. I.E. read at the same rate as you write.